# Fetching Discord Channel Members

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am attempting to fetch all the members of a certain Discord **voice** channel using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/)

I have a function trying to do this right now. It takes in an `interaction`, that is given when a user runs a slash command on Discord. The `options` parameter is simply the channel they pass in to the command.

[image: This is what running the command looks like]

```
const execute = async (interaction, options) => {
  if (interaction.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_GUILD)) {
    await interaction.guild.members.fetch();
    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
    const channelInput = options.getChannel('channel');
    const channel = await interaction.member.guild.channels.fetch(channelInput.id);
    const members = channel.members.map(member => member.id);
    console.log(members); // [ '143100912687251456', '143100912687251622' ]
  }
}
```

The issue is that it does not update properly if the user changes channels. If I restart the bot, and run the command, it executes perfectly. But if I were to change to another voice channel, it still thinks I am in the old one and not the new one.

This is probably because it is fetching some sort of cache. Does anyone know how to fetch their API directly instead of a local cache that isn't updating?

Comment: I don't quite get this. Why can't you use the voice channel the member is connected to?

Comment: @caTS I am trying to get a list of all the users in a certain voice channel. The user doesn't necessarily have to be in the voice channel to fetch the members of that channel.

Comment: Is `options.getChannel("channel")` always returning the same channel? Have you confirmed this with a log?

Comment: @caTS Indeed - if the user inputs a certain channel into the command, it always gets the correct channel. It just doesn't seem to update the member list.

Comment: So... is the channel correct, and the member list wrong because it isn't updated? Or is the channel incorrect and the member list is just plain wrong based on that.

Comment: @caTS Ah sorry, poor wording on my part. The channel is correct. The member list is wrong because it isn't being updated properly, which I'm assuming is because it's fetching from a local cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add GuildVoiceStates Intent

```js
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    ],
```

Comment: You're a legend! Yes, upgrading my bot to discord v14 and adding this intent worked. Thank you